# Kubernetes Autoscaler not working on Azure AKS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created `AKS` cluster on `Azure` and created some deployments. Since one of my deployment required `autoscaling` i have enabled HPA on it, but it is not working. It is unable to get metrics from metrics server. Getting below error. Can some one help me on it?

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                  From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                 ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       12m (x2 over 13m)    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  12m (x2 over 13m)    horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  10m (x10 over 12m)   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  failed to get cpu utilization: missing request for cpu
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric       3m5s (x39 over 12m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  missing request for cpu
```

Comment: How did you create `HPA`? Using commend or YAML manifest? Did you create it based on K8s docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale-walkthrough/#create-horizontal-pod-autoscaler ?

Comment: hi, i have created it with command "kubectl autoscale deployment azure-vote-front --cpu-percent=50 --min=3 --max=10" as given on the link "https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/aks/tutorial-kubernetes-scale#autoscale-pods".

Comment: 1. Provide output of `$ kubectl describe hpa`. 2. Provide output of `$ kubectl describe deployment <your-deployment-name>`, you can edit question and post it there to better visibility. 3. What AKS clusters versions are you using? 4. HPA sometimes need a few minutes to apply everything. Do you still have issue after ~10 minutes?

Comment: Do you enable the autoscale in AKS?

Answer (score 0):

First, install the [Metrics Server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) by applying [these YAML files](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/tree/master/deploy/1.8%2B).

Verify that the installation succeeded with:

```sh
kubectl get --raw=/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Second, make sure that all the containers of your Deployment have CPU resource requests:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
<...>
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: foo
        name: foo
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
```

Third, configure the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler as you already did and observe the events.